# Insert table data from .NET dataset into SAS data file via OLEDB

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oledb, sas

I have C# .NET code with a DataSet (System.Data.DataSet) containing one table of data, and I'm trying to create a new SAS data table on a SAS server and then push the data into it using C#.

Right now, I can create the new table on the SAS server, but I'm not sure how to transfer the data. I tried using this insert command (exportData is the DataSet):

```
"INSERT INTO SASUSER." + SAStableName + " SELECT * FROM " + exportData.Tables[0].TableName
```

But it thinks that the exportData table name is supposed to be a SAS library name. All I get when searching the web is examples that only take data out of SAS, which is easy with a TableDirect command type and the OLEDB fill method. It seems to be not so easy to reverse the process.

Note: I'm using the sas.IOMProvider provider in my connectionstring.

Thanks

**EDIT:** After all the searching I've been doing, I assume you can't really do this. I tried using SQL parameterization, but the SAS provider doesn't support that. I finally decided to use a simple for loop to add the values since all my source and target tables contain the same columns. Semi-pseudo code:

```
DateTime time = (System.DateTime)exportTable.Rows[i]["time"];
object value = exportTable.Rows[i]["value"];
"INSERT INTO SASUSER." + tableName + " (time, value) VALUES (" + time.Ticks + " , " + value + ")"
```

I'm still having trouble with loading dates into a new SAS table using an SQL INSERT clause (see code above). Not sure how they're supposed to be formatted. The time values in the source table (exportTable) are DateTime objects, so the cast is valid.

Comment: Alan Churchill, this one's for you!

Comment: Consider listing the columns on your target table. Don't use `*`, but rather an explicit list of columns on your source table. i.e. `INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2) SELECT ColA, ColB FROM OtherTable;`

Comment: @p.campbell I've actually done this in my updated workaround code (see edit), but the problem is that when I try to specify the .NET `DataSet` data in the SQL clause, it thinks the `DataSet` is a table and throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to do it as an INSERT from the dataset, can you approach it from the opposite direction do it as an EXPORT to to the table (SASUSER.tablename)?

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003102702.htm

Comment: I'm coding in C#, so I can't directly use SAS code. I can connect to a SAS workspace to execute some SAS code from inside C#, but it is a bit cumbersome and I would like to avoid doing that if possible.

Comment: I see -- in that case, are you using a data adapter to fill the tables in your dataset?  If so, you need to `.add()` to your datatable, and then `.update` your data adapter in order to push the changes back to the table.  Some info here (skip the top part covering Access -- the Sql-server part starts about half-way down)

Comment: I am using a data adapter. Are you saying I should create an empty datatable and fill it with the data from my source dataset then use `.update`? Did you mean to submit a link?

Comment: You already have the datatable I think -- exportData.Tables[0] -- so that's the one you would add rows to.  And then whatever dataset you're using to connect that datatable object to the actual table in the database would be where you could call .update.

Comment: I'd just like to give a big thanks for all the help you're giving me :). The table in exportData is already filled with data from a previous set of code that uses `.fill` - I'm transferring data between databases. `.update` doesn't do anything - it returns the value 0 (lines updated). I think `.update` only replaces old values? EDIT: sorry hadn't read that link you gave me.

Comment: .fill is how you get the data adapter to copy data from your actual database table into your application's datatable object.  .update moves the data in the opposite direction.  (At least, it 'should' do that...).  If you call .update directly after .fill, there are no changes...  You would need to call .fill, then .add, and then .update.

Comment: Using `.update` with an updated datatable as its parameter gives the error `"Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows."` So we're back to our original problem. Thanks for all your help. I'll post if I find a better way than a for loop.